# trying to get rid of some character utf8_encode wont fix

Tags: php, encoding

Well i have some places in a site i am making where title are somewhat screwy

I've tried using `utf8_encode` and `html_entity_decode(stripslashes($title),ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")` and several other solution which didn't work. i cant seem to get rid of them: here is an example:

title before my attempts:

`New Era Miami Dolphins NFLÂ® 9FIFTYâ�¢ Solid Snap Miami Dolphins - Zappos.com Free Shipping BOTH Ways`

here it is after utf8_encode and html entity

`New Era Miami Dolphins NFLÂ® 9FIFTYâ¢ Solid Snap Miami Dolphins - Zappos.com Free Shipping BOTH Ways`

its still problematic - is there a way to just get rid of those ?

Comment: Where does the input come from? From db? To me the output looks correct utf8 characters. What that output is supposed to look/say?

Comment: the autoput should be english only. its not from DB its from website's title tag

Comment: stripslashes strips all slashes from string and html_entity_decode converts html entities to their applicable characters, so those are not useful for you. If you just want to get rid of the strange characters use: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the title you have is UTF-8 encoded, but the HTML page you're embedding it in isn't actually marked as being UTF-8, so the browser is interpreting the text using the default character set, which is probably ISO-8859-1.

Assuming that all text on the page is, in fact, UTF-8 (or US-ASCII, which is a subset of it), the easiest solution is to just send the appropriate HTTP headers (and/or meta tags) to indicate the correct character set.  In particular, in PHP you can do:

```
header( "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" );
```

or you can include the equivalent meta tag in the head section of the HTML code:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

or, in HTML5, simply:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can allways borrow function from wordpress (seems_utf8) and modifie to your needs:

```
function remove_none_utf8($str) {
    $ret = '';

    $length = strlen($str);

    for ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $ok = true;

        $c = ord($str[$i]);

        if ($c < 0x80) $n = 0; # 0bbbbbbb

        elseif (($c & 0xE0) == 0xC0) $n=1; # 110bbbbb

        elseif (($c & 0xF0) == 0xE0) $n=2; # 1110bbbb

        elseif (($c & 0xF8) == 0xF0) $n=3; # 11110bbb

        elseif (($c & 0xFC) == 0xF8) $n=4; # 111110bb

        elseif (($c & 0xFE) == 0xFC) $n=5; # 1111110b

        else continue; # Does not match any model


        for ($j=0; $j<$n; $j++) { # n bytes matching 10bbbbbb follow ?

            if ((++$i == $length) || ((ord($str[$i]) & 0xC0) != 0x80)) {
                            $ok = false;

                continue;
                    }

        }
            if ($ok === true) $ret .= $str[$i];

    }

    return $ret;

}
```

So you can use it like this:

```
$str = "New Era Miami Dolphins NFLÂ® 9FIFTYâ�¢ Solid Snap Mi";
echo remove_none_utf8($str);
```